# Android Studio 0.8.1 Manifest Merger ${applicationId} not available

Tags: android, manifest

I am currently working on an application that has a few build variants, also a few product flavors, and in each build variant the package name suffix is different. I want to use ${applicationId} so I can have multiple build variants available on a single device.

```
<provider
            android:name="${applicationId}.providers.LocatorSearchSuggestionProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.providers.LocatorSearchSuggestionProvider" />
```

I have tried the following and it doesn't work. I have also tried packageName. Also in the build.gradle files I have applicationId specified in defaultConfig.

Edit:
   currently in the AndroidManifest.xml file I am getting a Cannot resolve symbol '${applicationId}' error. 
   also in my build.gradle file I have included applicationId

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
    useOldManifestMerger false
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.sample.android.login'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
```

Would appreciate any help on this, thanks!!!

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Do you get an error? If so, please include it in your question.

Comment: Also just for anyone else having that issue, I was trying to set the name of the broadprovider and using ${applicationId} in the name field. Instead I had to use it in the authority field and work like a charm. Problem fixed!

Comment: have you got any solution ?

Comment: My above comment suggests that I was making a mistake in using the ${applicationId} in the incorrect field and should have been using this in the authority field of the broadcast. Please make sure you are using ${applicationId} in the correct field.

Comment: @ahmad you should add your comments as a proper answer - I almost missed the solution seeing no one answered it.